# Python recursion evaluate only if necessary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have these two functions:

```
def s(x,y,z):
   if x <= 0:
       return y
   return z

def f(a,b):
    return s(b, a+1, f(a,b-1)+1)
```

If I were to try and find `f(5,2)` in my head, it would go like this:

```
f(5,2) = s(2,6,f(5,1)+1)
f(5,1) = s(1,6,f(5,0)+1)
f(5,0) = s(0,6,f(5,-1)+1) = 6
f(5,1) = 7
f(5,2) = 8
```

I never evaluate `f(5,-1)` because it is not needed. The `s` function is going to return 6, since argument `x` is zero, thus evaluation of argument `z` is unnecessary.

If I were however to try and run this in python, it would keep recursing forever or or until I get a maximum recursion depth error, presumably because python wants to evaluate all the arguments before executing the `s` function.

My question is, how would I go about implementing these functions, or any similar scenario, in such a way that the recursion stops when it is no longer needed? Would it be possible to delay the evaluation of each argument until it is used in the function?

Comment: Python can't know what `f()` will be bound to each time you execute the function body, as other code is free to re-bind `f()`. So *Python* can't optimise this, because it is a dynamic language.

Comment: So, if you as a programmer know that you don't need to make the additional `f()` recursive call when `b <= 0`, then test for that condition explicitly, in `f()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That makes sense, but it would require me to merge the logic of `s()` and `f()` which I would like to avoid. That is why I made them separate functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mind is working with 'insider knowledge' of how `s()` works. Python can't, so it can only follow the strict rules that all argument expressions to a call will have to be evaluated before the call can be made.

Python is a highly dynamic language, and at every step of execution, both `s` and `f` can be rebound to point to a different object. This means Python can't optimise recursion or inline function logic. It can't hoist the `if x <= 0` test out of `s()` to avoid evaluating the value for `z` first.

If you as a programmer know the third expression needs to be avoided in certain circumstances, you need to make this optimisation yourself. Either merge the logic in `s` into `f` manually:

```
def f(a, b):
    if b <= 0:
        return a + 1
    return f(a, b - 1) + 1
```

or postpone evaluating of the third expression until `s()` has determined if it needs to be calculated at all, by passing in a callable and make `s` responsible for evaluating it:

```
def s(x, y, z):
   if x <= 0:
       return y
   return z()   # evaluate the value for z late

def f(a, b):
    # make the third argument a function so it is not evaluated until called
    return s(b, a+1, lambda: f(a, b - 1) + 1)
```

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for the explanation of why python has been designed to behave this way.

Answer (score 3):

When a function is called, all arguments are fully evaluated before they're passed to the function. In other words, `f(5,-1)` is being executed before `s` is even started.

Fortunately there's an easy way to evaluate expressions on demand: functions. Instead of passing the *result* of `f(a,b-1)` to `z`, pass it a *function* that computes that result:

```
def s(x,y,z):
   if x <= 0:
       return y
   return z()  # z is a function now

def f(a,b):
    return s(b, a+1, lambda:f(a,b-1)+1)

print(f(5,2))  # output: 8
```

Comment: That is *exactly* the kind of neat workaround I was hoping to get.